# Lists iteration in python ( Assigning values to variables )

Tags: python, list

If i have lists for example:

```
['6'] #Number
['!'] #Punctuation
['r'] #Alphabet
['8'] #Number
['/'] #Punctuation
['e'] #Alphabet
['5'] #Number
[':'] #Punctuation
['l'] #Alphabet
```

I use `data = line.strip().split(' ')` to convert it into this form from a csv file.
I am trying to assign the elements in the lists to their respective variable
For example number will contain the lists that have numbers in it, punctuation will contain the lists that have punctuation in it and alphabet will have lists with alphabets.

What I can't understand is if I do something like

```
number = data[0], punc = data[1], alpha = data[2]
```

I get an error:

```
List index out of range.
```

So how can i solve this problem?

My code,

```
for line in new_file:
      text = [line.strip() for line in line.split(' ')]
```

Comment: Can you add your code to question?

Comment: Okay i have entered my code in the question!!

Comment: @Luke please edit the question with your code

Comment: Could you please change `[line.strip() for line in line.split(' ')]` to something like `[word.strip() for word in line.split(' ')]`? That makes much more sense...

Comment: okay i will do that!

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code appears to be fine

```
for line in new_file:
      text = [line.strip() for line in line.split(' ')]
```

however if you are doing the following

```
for line in new_file:
      text = [line.strip() for line in line.split(' ')]
      number = text[0], punc = text[1], alpha = text[2]
```

You may ran into problems..take for example a line in your file below

```
"hello world"
```

if you split this line you will have a list like ["hello", "world"].This list contains two elements.

Now if you assign this result like `text=["hello", "world"]`

and you place this result in a variable like

```
alpha = text[2]
```

You will certainly recieve `List index out of range.` ..Why?

**Because text[2] does not exist!**

Some lines may contain less then 3 words (like in this example)

**Revise your approach**

Try using a dictionary approach

```
alpha={"alphabet":[]}
numb={"alphabet":[]}
punc={"punctuation":[]}
```

..iterate through the file and use list comprehension to select all punctuation, letters, etc and add it your the respective dictionary elements... If you are having trouble post your revised codes

**EDIT A WORKING EXAMPLE HOW I WOULD TACKLE THIS**

Let say I have a file named new_file and has the content below

```
hello my name is repzERO
AND THIS IS my age: 100 years
```

A python script I tried

```
import re
new_file=open("new_file","r")
alpha={"alphabet":[]}
numb={"number":[]}
punc={"punctuation":[]}
all_punctuation=""

for line in new_file:
    alpha["alphabet"]+=[c for c in line if re.search("[a-zA-Z ]",c)]
    numb["number"]+=[c for c in line if re.search("[0-9]",c)]
    punc["punctuation"]+=[c for c in line if re.search("[^\w\s]",c)]

print(alpha)
print(numb)
print(punc)
```

output

```
{'alphabet': ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'r', 'e', 'p', 'z', 'E', 'R', 'O', 'A', 'N', 'D', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'I', 'S', ' ', 'I', 'S', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'a', 'g', 'e', ' ', ' ', 'y', 'e', 'a', 'r', 's']}
{'number': ['1', '0', '0']}
{'punctuation': [':']}
```

Comment: I am trying really hard but cannot get anywhere!
Using dictionary is good idea but how my program proceeds, it would be impossible to locate certain elements!
My main question was that if i had that list i posted in my question, how would i spot a particular element let's say ['r'] which is at line 3.
Using index i suppose! data['x'] where x is some index i don't know how to use to let the program print just ['r'] from that entire file carrying lists!

Comment: Ah! the search function.. Helps me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your lists seems to have less elements.

Something like this:

```
yourVariableName = ["what", "ever", "elements", "are", "here"]
```

is called a list. The list above has 5 elements. You can access the elements with a numeric index `i`:

```
yourVariableName[i]
```

where `i` is in this case either `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` or `4` (or negative number when you want to count from the end). When you try

```
yourVariableName[5]
```

or even higher, you get an "index out of range" error.

Comment: I know how to do that, my list has less elements but my task is to assign it to a variable!
if line 1 has ['5'] that mean number = data['i dont know what index goes here']
same for puctuation and alphabets!
It's just this index usage i can't understand.
What you explained is pretty basic and i know how to do that

Comment: Do you mean you want to append an element to the list? Like `list.append("whatever")`? Or do you rather want a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, i want to append. I believe dictionary would be an easier approach!!

Comment: Can we append this to a dictionary??
Considering a key to be number and values to be the numbers in the list!

Comment: Yes you can append to the Value